# Modifying standard keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm looking for a way to modify the system keyboards without using a custom keyboard.

For example, I'd like to overlay an extra UIView or cover up a button programmatically. How can I get the instance of a keyboard that the system provides if you don't specify an inputView for a UITextField or UITextView?

My idea is to get a reference to the keyboard and insert a subview or two before it is shown. There doesn't seem to be a public API for this (With good reason I'm sure).

I'm not concerned with accessing private APIs or app store rejection since this is a private, in-house app.

Answer (score 3):

Sign up for UIKeyboardDidShow notification

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

then in the handler

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //Locate keyboard view
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {

        for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES) {
                // Add your custom view
                UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(83, 174, 156, 38)];
                customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];

                [keyboard addSubview:customView];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            }
        }
    }
}
```